# Java GUI clear button

Tags: java

I am writing a code to convert celsius to Fahrenheit  and vice versa. I want to implement the clear method using an anonymous listener. Also, how can I make it check the validity of inputs(only integers) and catch any exception? The code runs but I have problems with these two things. Any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.*;

public class TempConverter extends JFrame
    {
private static final double CelsiusToFarenheit = 9.0 / 5.0;
private static final double FahrenheitToCelsius = 5.0 / 9.0;
private static final int base = 32;
private int win_wid = 500;
private int win_hei = 200;

private JLabel fahrenLab, CelsiusLab;
private JTextField fahrenField , celsiusField;

private JButton convertBut, clearBut;



public TempConverter()
{
    this.setTitle("convert Temperature");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(win_wid, win_hei);
    
    initWin();
    
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void initWin()
{
    int titleFontSize = 25;
    int labFontSize = 15;
    
    Font titleFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, titleFontSize);
    Font labFont = new Font("Aria", Font.BOLD, labFontSize);
    
    JPanel northPan = new JPanel();
    JLabel titleLab = new JLabel("Convert to Celsius");
    titleLab.setFont(titleFont);
    titleLab.setForeground(Color.blue);
    northPan.add(titleLab);
    this.add(northPan, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    
    JPanel centerPan = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
    fahrenLab = new JLabel("Enter Fahrenheit temp.   ");
    fahrenLab.setFont(labFont);
    fahrenLab.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    centerPan.add(fahrenLab);
    fahrenField = new JTextField();
    centerPan.add(fahrenField);
    
    CelsiusLab = new JLabel("Celcius temp.   ");
    CelsiusLab.setFont(labFont);
    CelsiusLab.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    centerPan.add(CelsiusLab);
    
    celsiusField = new JTextField();
    celsiusField.setFont(labFont);
    centerPan.add(celsiusField);
    this.add(centerPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    JPanel southPan = new JPanel();
    convertBut = new JButton("Convert");
    convertBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent me)
        {
            
            //processTemp();
    
double celsius = 0, fahrenheit = 0;
DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
if (TempConverter.this.celsiusField.getText() == null || "".equals(TempConverter.this.celsiusField.getText().trim())) 
{
    // convert from fahrenheit to celsius
    fahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(TempConverter.this.fahrenField.getText());
    celsius = (fahrenheit - TempConverter.base) *   TempConverter.FahrenheitToCelsius;
    TempConverter.this.celsiusField.setText(" " + twoDigits.format(celsius));
} else if (TempConverter.this.fahrenField.getText() == null || "".equals(TempConverter.this.fahrenField.getText().trim())) 
{
       // convert from celsius to fahrenheit
       celsius = Double.parseDouble(TempConverter.this.celsiusField.getText());
       fahrenheit = celsius * TempConverter.CelsiusToFarenheit + TempConverter.base;
       TempConverter.this.fahrenField.setText(" " + twoDigits.format(fahrenheit));
}
try 
        {
fahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(TempConverter.this.fahrenField.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
 //alert the user       
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are allowed to introduce numbers only for 
 temperature");

   }
        }
        
    }
    );
            
    convertBut.setFont(labFont);
    
    clearBut = new JButton("Clear");
    clearBut.setFont(labFont);
    
    clearBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent me)
        {
            southPan.add(clearBut);
            System.err.print("Clear Button clicked");
            //clear();
            southPan southPan2 = new southPan();
 add(southPan2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    });
    
    
    southPan.add(convertBut);
    southPan.add(clearBut);
    this.add(southPan, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new TempConverter();
}

}
```

Comment: Usually, you should ask one question only. Anyways.. Regarding your first question, you should simply only clear your `JTextField`s via `fahrenField.setText("")` for example and your `JLabel`s via `fahrenLab.setText("")`. This should do it, there is no need to create a new `JPanel`.

Comment: Regarding your second question: If you want only `Integer`s to be valid input, I would highly suggest you to use a [`JSpinner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html). If you want to keep your `JTextField`s, you could simply use a try-catch to parse the input and to catch any `NumberFormatException` when parsing to `int` and handle it from there.

Answer (score 1):

at first this is how to control the input in the JTextField , try this code :

```
YourTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyTyped(e);
            char x = e.getKeyChar();

            if(Character.isAlphabetic(x)){
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

this code will make your JTextField only accepts anything but Alphabetic , you can change the isAlphabetic(x) by other things that you want , for your case about only accepts digits you can try the next code :

```
YourTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyTyped(e);
            char x = e.getKeyChar();

            if(!Character.isDigit(x)){
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

i don't understand what are you mean with this line :
**I want to implement the clear method using an anonymous listener**

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use a `DocumentFilter`. This will work even if text is pasted to the text field.